# BCP - Export Query to Tab Delimited Text File

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I am using SSMS and trying to export a query to a text file using T-SQL (I know there are options in the tool itself to do this, but I need this code for a stored procedure).

I found examples but none of them seem to work and each gives a different error message:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM [REPORT_ReviewStatus]" queryout "\\sd-eefx-5586\Report Outputs\REPORT_H75_ReviewStatus.txt" -T -c'
```

The above gives me an error about:

- Copy direction must be either 'in' or 'out'.
- Syntax Error in 'queryout'.

So I try it using "Out"

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM [REPORT_ReviewStatus]" out "\\sd-eefx-5586\Report Outputs\REPORT_H75_ReviewStatus.txt" -T -c'
```

This gives me the following errors:

- Password:
- CTLIB Message: - L1/O1/S1/N138/1/0:
- : user api layer: external error: A data length of 255 exceeds the maximum length allowed for password data.
- Setting connection properties failed.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I use BCP for this, or is there something else to do that doesn't use SSIS (I will do this if necessary, but would like to avoid it if possible)

Comment: Are you using sybase or microsft sql server? "CTLIB" is, i believe, an error from sybase tools / db engine.

Comment: And i suggest you divide your issue into smaller chunks. First write a static bcp command that can successfully run and generate your file using a command window. Once you get that working, you should be able to integrate the same logic into your stored procedure (though it is NOT recommended). Though it should be obvious - tsql is not really designed access the file system or do ETL - consider that a warning that your path may become more difficult. And yes - do review the documentation to help you with basic syntax.

Comment: I don't recommend running `xp_cmdshell` from a stored procedure. It hogs a server thread, and has security implications. Use a Powershell script instead, i.e. execute a stored procedure *from* PS to do what you need to do, then execute `bcp` from PS to get the output

Answer (score 1):

I used a similar query that works but I wrote `EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell` instead of what you have `EXEC xp_cmdshell`